# How to get that $M J \subsetneq M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Let $\Lambda$ be an artin algebra. $M$ is a finitely generated left $\Lambda$-module. Then we have that $M$ is also a right $End_{\Lambda}(M)$-module. Let $J$ be the Jacobson radical of $End_{\Lambda}(M)$. Then how to make sure $M J \subsetneq M$? (If $M$ is a projective module, then I can get that $J=Hom_{\Lambda}(M, radM)$, so $MJ$ is a proper submodule of $M$. How to get that for the general case?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $M$ is regarded as a right $\operatorname{End}(M)$-module, then $MJ$ is equal to what is called the radical of $M$, that is the intersection of all maximal (right) submodules. In particular, it is a proper submodule.

To see the statement that $MJ$ is contained in every maximal $\operatorname{End}(M)$-submodule of $M$ let $M'$ be such a maximal submodule. Then $M/M'$ is simple and thus, $(M/M')J=0$, thus, $MJ\subseteq M'$.

To get that $SJ=0$ for each simple $\operatorname{End}(M)$-module note that the map $A\to S, a\mapsto sa$ defines a right module homomorphism. For $s\neq 0$, this is surjective. Thus, the kernel is a maximal right ideal of $A$ and hence, $J(A)$ is contained in it.

Comment: $J \subset End(M)$, how to understand $(M/ M') J$, in other words, what is the action of $J$ on $M/M'$? And how to get that $(M /M') J =0$? Another question is that $rad M= rad \Lambda M$ when $M$ is a left $\Lambda$-module, so we can also get that $radM=MJ$ when $M$ is seen as a right $End(M)$-module?

Comment: $(M/M')J$ is to be understood in the usual sense: $M'$ is an $\operatorname{End}(M)$-submodule of $M$, so the action is given by $(m+M')j=mj+M'$ for $j\in J$ or more general $j\in \operatorname{End}(M)$. And yes to the statement for right modules. If you have the result already for left modules, you can prove the corresponding result for right modules by applying the result for left modules to the opposite algebra.